# Empty space between navigationbar and view

Tags: rubymotion

I'm experiencing this weird behaviour once I initiate an application root controller with a UINavigationController
On first launch, there is an empty space between the navigationbar and first viewcontroller controller.
but the full content is displayed after I swtiched to another view and back to the first one.
Is something wrong with this?

```
tab_bar_controller = RootViewController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)
@window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(tab_bar_controller)
```

Thanks for your help.

[image: empty space between navigationbar and view content]

Comment: Can you post your first ViewController code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not considered "proper" to put a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController`:

> [UINavigationController#initWithRootViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ... rootViewController:
>   The view controller that resides at the bottom of the navigation stack.
>   This object *cannot be an instance of the UITabBarController class*.

The opposite - a UINavigationController as one of the UITabBarController child view controllers - *is* allowed.

```
nav_controller = RootViewController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)
@window.rootViewController = UITabBarController.alloc.init
@window.rootViewController.viewControllers = [nav_controller]
```

Even if you did get this figured out, your app would ultimately be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the content in the `viewWillAppear` callback.